# Is possible to set Carousel Pages visible on condition in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have the following code in Xamarin.Forms:

```
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App.Views.SliderPage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.ViewModels"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:App.Views"
          mc:Ignorable="d"
         >
<CarouselPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Complete" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" />
</CarouselPage.ToolbarItems>
<pages:APage/>
<pages:BPage/>
<pages:CPage/>
</CarouselPage>
```

I want to display **pages** regarding condition like IsVisible, but I couldn't find any solution. Is that even possible here?

Comment: You will need to load pages into the CarouselPage via the ItemSource property.  There are probably a bunch of ways to do this depending on your app architecture but I would maintain an ObservableCollection in the CarouselPage's viewmodel and add/remove pages from it based on your conditions.  Then use the approach show in the *Populate a CarouselPage with a template* section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page

Comment: @HumanWrites oh okay. It is better to redefine design then. Thank you for your answer